# Idle relearn almost daily

Tags: toyota

After having a problem with the idle speed for some time, a collegae told me about the relearn procedure. After trying it, the car was idling better for some days.

Now I have done this procedure almost twice a week for a total of 6 times, because the car won't idle correctly. After the procedure the car always idles correctly.

I'm no mechanic but I don't think it has anything to do with the throttle body as the car idles correctly after the procedure.

Why do I need to do this procedure so often?

---

### Update:

The make and model of the car: Toyota Ipsum 2007. No check lights are on (cel).

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/model/engine of your Toyota? Is a Check Engine Light (CEL) present? Has there been since you started having this issue? If so, what are the codes?